# OutofMemory in Antlr4.Runtime

Tags: c#, antlr4

I recently completed a grammar to parse Verilog HDL code.   When I try to use it the memory utilization blows up to peak close to 10 GB.  This is huge making it impossible for me to use this within a 32bit process.  I am using Runtime version 4.5.  I tried upgrading to version 4.5.2 but that threw an exception as it reached 8 GB of memory utilization even in 64 bit mode.  Can anyone offer any suggestions about what to do get the memory under control?

Comment: I ran an experiment that behaves strangely.  If create an instance of the parser and parse some code it takes several minutes and several GB to complete.  Then I create a new instance of the parser and parse the code again and it completes almost instantly with minimal memory.  This makes no sense.  If I were using the same instance, I could believe there may be some caching I am not aware of but these are two different instances so there should be no common state.  What more, if I modify the code a little it again parses quickly.

Comment: However, if I parser a completely new piece of code it starts taking a long time again and more memory.  If I could understand this, I might be able to understand the memory problem too.